# Filtering jqgrid table with user checkbox values?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9fOA.png**strong text**

I need to filter client data when user select checkboxes using jquery or javascript.

Image attached here....

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used -  Guriddo jqGrid or free-jqGrid and what is your datatype - i.e where is performed the search local or server side?

Comment: I'm using 3.5 of free jqgrid and my data type is a number but sample shows string. I want to perform this action at client side and sample image was attached. Thanks.

Comment: I recommend you to search here. There are a lot of useful post here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've attained the expected result by using reverse selection(passing not selected checkbox value to the grid table).